vite-plugin-svgr - How to really generate viewBox from svg sizes?
I need to generate viewbox for svg from their height and width.
I tried this options in vite.config.ts:
svgr({
  include: '**/*.svg?react',
  svgrOptions: {
    svgo: true,
    svgoConfig: { removeDimensions: true, },
    svgProps: { height: '12', width: '12', },
  },
})

add this
svgr({
  include: '**/*.svg?react',
  svgrOptions: {
    svgo: true,
    svgoConfig: { ['removeDimensions'], },
    svgProps: { height: '12', width: '12', },
  },
})

But there is still no viewbox attribute in svg. How can i fix that?
package.json
"vite-plugin-svgr": "4.2.0",
"svgo": "3.2.2",


The height and width of an svg is how big it is. The viewBox is how big its contents ate. There's not necessarily any connection between the two at all.

Ideally your SVG assets should already have a suitable viewBox. SVGO may strip these valuable data due to aggressive default settings (you should definitely check the configs). Just setting the viewBox to the desired layout dimensions will most likely result in cropped graphics or padding (too much surrounding whitespace). This is important if you're mixing different icon libraries: google's material icons are based on a 24x24 viewBox whereas fontAwesome uses a ~512x512 (with variable widths). All in all, try to retain different viewBoxes as they are a part of the design concept.

"Ideally your SVG assets should already have a suitable viewBox" - But they don't. And height/width can be changed with props. because now SVG is a React component. So I have SVG-file with "<svg width="8" height="14...>" and "width={12} height={12}" like a props in component from that file. And now my SVG is looking not pretty well on the page because of missing viewBox attribute. vite-plugin-svgr can generate and provide viewBox from basic width/height attributes in svg file, but I don't know how to do it :(
